# Can you assign object instances directly to a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, class, instance

I've defined a class called Space, meant to represent spaces on a 9x9 board. I want to generate 81 instances at the beginning of the program by assigning them to elements of a list that I intend to use as a 2D array.

Here's the class:

```
class Space:
    def __init__(self, x_coord, y_coord):
        self.row = x_coord
        self.column = y_coord
```

Here's one of my attempts to assign instances to a list (also called space):

```
for i in xrange(1,9):
   for j in xrange(1,9):
        space[i][j] = Space(i,j)
```

My goal here is to be able to reference instances using the list indices as if they were coordinates, ie `space[1][2].value = 3`

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there a better way to generate instances en masse? Thanks!

Edit: (My response below in more readable form)

The script runs, but it looks like my list is not defined when I try to access it in the command prompt

```
>>> space[1][2].value = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'space' is not defined
>>> space[1][1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'space' is not defined
```

Comment: What's the problem with your "attempt?"

Comment: Please add your traceback to your question so we can read it.

Comment: Well, that _is_ a problem, but it's a separate one. Where have you defined `space`? You _have_ defined it somewhere, right?

Comment: It sounds like you want inherit from `list` or add a `__getitem__` function.

Comment: Well, I thought I had defined it in the `space[i][j] = Space(i,j)` line. That being said, I've also stuck a `space = []` before the loop, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're never creating the `space` lists you're trying to use to hold your `Space` objects. Here's one way to do it, by starting with an empty list and appending the values into the list as you go:

```
space = [] # initially empty list
for i in range(9):
    column = [] # create an empty list to hold a column of values
    for j in range(9):
        column.append(Space(i, j)) # add the object to the column
    space.append(column) # add the column to the outer list
```

A cleaner, more "Pythonic" solution is to use nested [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), as in isedev's answer:

```
space = [[Space(i, j) for j in range(9)] for i in range(9)]
```

As a final note, using the same word with only capitalization differences for different things in your code is probably a bad idea. It can be OK to use a variable named `foo` to hold a single `Foo` instance, but a better name would indicate what the instance is for, e.g. `foo_for_frobbing`. In your case, `board` might be a better name than `space` for your list of `Space` instances.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use 0-based indexing, but this will achieve what you want:

```
space = [[Space(i,j) for j in range(9)] for i in range(9)]
```

Comment: This seems to have the same issue my attempt did: I can run the script, but any attempt to access the list gives me the error `NameError: name 'space' is not defined`

Comment: @smohyee: can you give a more complete example when you can that error. It generally indicates you haven't defined 'space' in the current scope.

Comment: Ah... there was a typo above too (missing 'in' between 'i' and 'range'). Now corrected.